# How do i CHECK if a year is between 2000 and the current year?

Tags: oracle, date, ddl

I need to create a table for automobiles.

Each automobile has a year of manufacture. The year of manufacture must be between 2000 and the current year.

```
year_manufacture INTEGER CONSTRAINT nn_automobiles_year_manufacture NOT NULL 
                             CONSTRAINT ck_automobiles_year_manufacture 
                   CHECK ((year_manufacture>= 2000)AND(year_manufacture<= "current year")),
```

Comment: Before thinking of any code - there is a logical flaw in the question, and I wonder if you have thought about it. Suppose you inserted a row for a new automobile in 2015. The year of manufacture was 2014, so that's OK. Now we are in 2019, and someone updates the table, changing the year of manufacture to 2017. Should this be allowed? If not, how are you going to prevent it? How will you know that **2015** has anything to do with the data in the table? The year in the table shows 2014, but there is no way to tell when the row itself was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if such a workaround helps.

Everything you've been already told stands. As you can't directly check the year against `SYSDATE`, create another column - `THIS_YEAR` - which won't be used anywhere in your code. It is automatically populated on each insert and gets current year.

Constraint (which can't be inline) then compares `YEAR_MANUFACTURE` with `THIS_YEAR`.

```
SQL> create table cars
  2    (id               number         constraint pk_cars primary key,
  3     name             varchar2(20)   not null,
  4     this_year        number(4)      default extract (year from sysdate),
  5     year_manufacture number(4),
  6     --
  7     constraint ch_year_manufacture check (year_manufacture between 2000 and this_year)
  8    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> -- OK - after 2000, before 2019 (which is the current year)
SQL> insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (1, 'BMW', 2005);

1 row created.

SQL> -- Wrong - before 2000
SQL> insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (2, 'Mercedes', 1998);
insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (2, 'Mercedes', 1998)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_YEAR_MANUFACTURE) violated


SQL> -- Wrong - after 2019 (which is the current year)
SQL> insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (3, 'Cooper', 2020);
insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (3, 'Cooper', 2020)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_YEAR_MANUFACTURE) violated


SQL> -- OK - current year
SQL> insert into cars (id, name, year_manufacture) values (4, 'Opel', 2019);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from cars;

        ID NAME                  THIS_YEAR YEAR_MANUFACTURE
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------------
         1 BMW                        2019             2005
         4 Opel                       2019             2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, according to the [Restrictions on Check Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205) :

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:
>
> [...]
>
> - Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (`CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `DBTIMEZONE`, `LOCALTIMESTAMP`, `SESSIONTIMEZONE`, `SYSDATE`, `SYSTIMESTAMP`, `UID`, `USER`, and `USERENV`)

Answer (score 1):

You can not create such a `CHECK` constraint containig `SYSDATE`, but use a `DML`(`Insert`) trigger to check the condition ( considering year_manufacture is of type date ) :

```
Create or Replace Trigger trg_chk_man_date
Before Insert On tab -- replace with your table's name
For Each Row
Begin
  if to_char(:new.year_manufacture,'YYYY') < 2000 
     or to_char(:new.year_manufacture,'YYYY') > to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') then
    Raise_Application_Error(-20001,'The Wrong Manufacture Year !');
  end if;
End;
```

If year_manufacture is numeric type column then just consider `:new.year_manufacture < 2000 and extract(year from sysdate) < :new.year_manufacture` as already @Wernfried Domscheit pointed out.

Comment: According question `year_manufacture` is an `INTEGER` not a `DATE` value - although a DATE value might be the better design.

Comment: exactly I directly considered as so @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create this with constraint. You could make a hack with virtual column but actually your requirement does not make much sense.

A value which is invalid today will be valid in five Months. However, a constraint must be valid (or invalid) at any time.

All you could do is to create a trigger which checks the year of manufacture at the time of insert or update. Would be like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_manufacture_date
   BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON automobiles
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.year_manufacture NOT BETWEEN 2000 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) THEN
      raise_application_error(20001, 'Manufacture must be between 2000 and current year');
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Isn't this should be `raise_application_error(-20001, ...` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, yes - I don't have the entire Oracle documentation in my head.

Comment: yes, the same problem for me. You remind me `for each row` :) , thanks.